# Does an AQP line check conducted by a part 121 carrier count as a flight review and instrument proficiency check for part 91 operations?

Tags: faa-regulations

If a pilot completes an [AQP](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/training/aqp/) program with a part 121 airline, does completion of all training and passing the line evaluation also qualify as a flight review and instrument proficiency check for continued part 91 operations?

Comment: For what purposes? For qualifying for continued operation with that company under either §121 or §135? For operation outside the air carrier under §91? For §107 remote pilot certification? As asked this is rather broad—if not *too* broad. I'm not voting to close, but you should clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if the AQP qualifies as a pilot proficiency check.  Most likely the the outcome will be a pilot proficiency check.

> §61.56   Flight review.
>
> > ...
> >
> > (d) A person who has, within the period specified in paragraph (c) of this section, passed any of the following need not accomplish the flight review required by this section:
> >
> > > (1) **A pilot proficiency check** or practical test conducted by an examiner, an approved pilot check airman, or a U.S. Armed Force, for a pilot certificate, rating, or operating privilege.